# Why does boto3.client("ecs").describe_tasks(...) not always have a stopCode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I have code which is similar to this (heavily stripped down, of course):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client("ecs")
response = client.describe_tasks(cluster="some cluster arn",
                                 tasks=["some task arn"])
task = response["tasks"][0]
if task["lastStatus"] == "STOPPED":
    if task["stopCode"] == "EssentialContainerExited":
        pass
```

This failed because of a key error in the last line. Reading [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html) and [some more docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/stop-task.html), I assumed that the `stopCode` would always exist when the `lastStatus` is `STOPPED`.

Why did that break?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-tasks.html - this doc for this specific API call has example output which doesn't have stopCode. I would think that if task is running or was never launched then it shouldn't have stopCode. In your case I would ask AWS Support to verify.

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha But when `task["lastStatus"] == "STOPPED"` then the task should not be running, right? And if it is stopped it should have launched?

Comment: Is there `stoppedReason` in same output? From docs: `stoppedReason -> (string) The reason that the task was stopped`. This call might have internal logic different to those `run-task, stop-task` calls, so unless someone more knowledgeable gives answer I would say asking support would be best approach

Comment: The problem is, that we had this code running for several weeks / called it probably several hundred times and it never failed. Now it failed. We re-ran it, and it doesn't fail again. I cannot reproduce the bug as I don't know what caused it.

Comment: I also cannot judge if this might occur more often or if this was a super rare event.